# Multiply two xarray DataArrays with different time length

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I have two dataarrays that are the same size in latitude and longitude space, but different in time space.

```
data1
xarray.DataArray (time: 28 latitude: 137 longitude: 261)

data2
xarray.DataArray (time: 224 latitude: 137 longitude: 261)
```

`data1` is daily data for February of 2020 (Feb 1-28), while `data2` is 3hourly data for Feb of 2020 (Feb 1-28). `data1` represents an array that I want to use to modify `data2` (and other dataarrays) by multiplying the two together. I want this done by taking the value of `data1` for each day to be multiplied against values that have the same day in `data2`.

For example, on Feb 1 `data1` might be 1.5, and on all hours during Feb 1, `data2` might be `[1,1.25,1,0.75,1,0,1,1.75]`. I want to multiply 1.5 (from `data1`) by all of all of the values from `data2`, while keeping the same time dimensionality as `data2`. This would result in a new array/list for that day being `[1.5,1.875,1.5,1.125,1.5,0,1.5,2.625]`. The same would then apply for future days (Feb 2, Feb 3, etc).

I am sure there is some sort of way to do this, whether that be with xarray or even just numpy, but am unsure of exactly how that would work. Preferably this would be done with xarray.